# Objective-C Double, Long Calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to calculate a long value divided by an integer to give me what I would expect to be a double, although the result I am getting is 0. The code I am using...

```
double daysByYear = daysSinceBirthdayToService/365;
NSLog(@"%d", daysByYear);
```

In this code, daysSinceBirthdayToService variable is a Long Double which can be NSLogged using the following code `(long)daysSinceBirthdayToService`

It is declaired in the header file as a property of

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger daysSinceBirthdayToService;
```

Can anybody help me out with this, thanks!

Comment: You must `%f`, not `%d` for format a `double`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that / between two longs will do an integral division.

To force a floating point division at least one of the operands needs to be cast to double.

e.g.

```
double daysByYear = daysSinceBirthdayToService/(double)365;
```

or if you have a literal make that a double by adding a decimal point

```
double daysByYear = daysSinceBirthdayToService/365.0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double daysByYear = daysSinceBirthdayToService/365.0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can it be that %d outputs decimal number not a double?

Comment: `%d` is for `int` values. `%f` should be used for `double`.

Comment: NSLog(@"%d", daysByYear); outputs double converted to integer so what's the problem?

Comment: No conversion is done by format specifiers. What would happen is that the %d specifier would say "I need an `int`". So it looks at the memory occupied by the argument (in this case a `double`) and interprets the bytes as the bytes of an `int`. Since the memory is actually not an `int`, the resulting output it likely to be garbage.

Comment: You will also get a compiler warning using `%d` with an argueent of type `double`.